# Xamarin.iOS - Using app groups to communicate between app extension and container app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I tried making an app extension in Xamarin.iOS and share data from the container app to the extension. I tried using app groups but Xamarin.iOS doesn't seem to support this (am I right?).

I created an app group in the Apple developper member center, and set it in the Entitlements.plist in both projects.

Here, I can get the container app to get the group path, but the app extension returns null :

`NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetContainerUrl("group.com.myApp.data");`

Is there a way to achieve that using Xamarin, or is it not currently supported?

Comment: I guess when functions are there the error might be somewhere else: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19

Comment: isn't that OSX only? At the top it says "This chapter describes property list keys specific to the OS X implementation of App Sandbox. They are not available in iOS.". I understand this is in the iOS Developer Library, but there is no reference to app extension IPC there...

Comment: Actually i have no clue. :-) But i think it might be something like you forget to register the container somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the container is registered in the container app. I found the solution and will post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: Please help me if you know about how to implement this feature in Xamarin Ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the app ID in the `GetContainerURL` call. I was using `NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetContainerUrl("group.com.myApp.data");` when I should have been using `NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetContainerUrl("group.com.myApp");`. The `.data` apparently wasn't part of this identifier string.

Comment: Please help me if you know about how to implement this feature in Xamarin Ios.

Comment: this is xamarin iOS

Comment: Please provide me sample code structure  for this..Because I have tried but not able to find that extension in share menu..I will appreciate your help.

Comment: I have used this below mentioned example.

Comment: In some example (ios native and swift) I have refereed that some value needs to be change in app group and in xamarin example I'm not able to find those kind of value. would you please help me on that.